# How to write multiple enum classes in a class

Tags: java, enums

I have a question on writing multiple enums in a java class. Can we have like this ?

Could you please help me on how to complete this ?

For Ex :

```
public final class Test{

    public enum Unit{
        HORIZONTAL("HORIZONTAL");

    }

    public enum Code {
        COMPANY ("COMPANY");
    }

    public enum Version{
        ONE(1)

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the Java Tutorial?  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Answer (score 6):

You indeed can have multiple enums defined in class, yet each of your enum would require a constructor to deal with the parameters in parenthesis, that is

```
public enum Unit {
    HORIZONTAL("HORIZONTAL"), VERTICAL("VERTICAL");
    private String unit;

    Unit(String unit) {
        this.unit = unit;
    }
}
```

or

```
Version(int versionNumber){}
```

For further explanation please specify the question.

Comment: Are you sure about that?

Comment: yeah but remember about the ";" in ONE(1);

Comment: @DawidBugajewski ,thank you for the prompt reply , I tried but giving "return type for the method is missing"

Comment: `public class Test {

 public enum Unit {
  HORIZONTAL("HORIZONTAL"), VERTICAL("VERTICAL");
 }

 public enum Code {

  INSURANCE("INSURANCE"), HEALTHCARE("HEALTHCARE");

 }

 public enum Version {
  ONE(1), TWO(2);
 }

 private String unit;

 public Unit(String unit) {
  this.unit = unit;

 }
}`

Comment: Edited the answer to help you more. The idea is to have the constructor and parameter in correct brackets. That is in the enum scope.

Answer (score 6):

An enum definition in Java is a class.  The language provides the syntactic features that are particular to enums, but as far as the JVM is concerned, the enum is a class.

In fact, an enum that is declared:

```
public enum MyConstants{ ... }
```

is implemented at the JVM as:

```
public static class Enum<MyConstants> { ... }
```

The rules for declaring enum classes is thus the same as for declaring classes.  A .java file may have only one public class.

You can therefore declare only one public enum in a .java file.  You may declare any number of package-private enums.

If you have multiple, closely related enums, there is no harm in declaring them all as nested members of an enclosing class:

```
public class MyEnumContainer {

    static enum MyEnum1 { ... }

    static enum MyEnum2 { ... }

    :
    :
}
```

In this case, you would need to import your MyEnclosingClass, or refer to the constants as MyEnclosingClass.MyEnum1.ENUM_ONE, for example.  Note that all enums are static classes, so using the static keyword doesn't penalize you, but it isn't necessary.

Each of the member enum definitions must stand alone (i.e., it must be a complete enum definition).  If you have constant-associated data, then each enum definition will need its own instance fields and constructor.  If you have constant-specific methods, each enum will need to provide the methods.

If you are concerned about a lot of code duplication, you can put the common code into a private static helper class, and then forward method calls to those within your enum definitions.

Using your enum definitions, the nested enums should look something like:

```
public final class Test{

    public enum Unit {
         HORIZONTAL ("HORIZONTAL"),
         VERTICAL   ("VERTICAL"),
         :
         :
         DIAGONAL   ("DIAGONAL");

         private final String e_name;

         Unit(String name)
             { this.e_name = name; }

         public String getName() { return e_name; }
    }

    public enum Code {
    :
    :
    }

    public enum Version{
    :
    :
    }
}
```

Comment: that was a very clear explanation, thank you very much !! yes both the approaches looks same and they both worked.