# Referencing One of Multiple Enums in a Class File

Tags: java, xml, enums

I'm having some issues referencing a specific enum within a class file.

This class file contains multiple enums. It looks like the following:

> ```
> public class MyEnumContainer {
>
>    static enum MyEnum1 { ... }
>
>    static enum MyEnum2 { ... }
>
>    :
>    :
> }
> ```

Here is my reference to the example above: [Multiple Enums in a Single Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282231/how-to-write-multiple-enum-classes-in-a-class)

I'm using this in an XML file. The reference is used in the `<type>` tag in a `<setting>` tag.

I currently have a reference to the MyEnumContainer. It looks like the following:
`<type>MyEnumContainer</type>`.

I've tried using `<type>MyEnumContainer.MyEnum1</type>` and `<type>MyEnumContainer$MyEnum1</type>` but the reference was not recognized.

**Note:** the software that processes this XML is **fully functional**. I **only** need to know how to properly reference a specific enum within a class file.

Comment: what does this xml file represent? what software do you have that reads the xml file? what does "perform as expected" mean?

Comment: @Joni The xml file is referenced in a piece of software I'm using. The software reads the class file fine, it's not an issue with the software. Because it's not pointing to that specific enum value within the class file, it is displaying incorrect information. What I mean by perform as expected is that I wish for the right information to populate. If the reference to this specific enum is correct, it will perform as expected. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to answer this question without knowing what "piece of software" you are using and how it works internally

Comment: @Joni It's part of a large project so I can't share the code. It hasn't been published anywhere yet either unfortunately. It's not the software. I just need a way to reference to the enum in this class file properly, that's all I'm trying to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your real problem is how your XML parser interprets the value in <type>. If it does not know how to get an enum from within a class, then there is nothing you can do. On the other hand, it may know how to get at the enum, but uses some arcane delimiter to separate the class name from the enum name. So

```
<type>MyEnumContainer#MyEnum1</type>
<type>MyEnumContainer*MyEnum1</type>
```

or

```
<type>MyEnumContainer(MyEnum1)</type>
<type>MyEnumContainer[MyEnum1]</type>
```

or

```
<type enum="MyEnum1">MyEnumContainer</type>
<type inner="MyEnum1">MyEnumContainer</type>
```

or maybe even

```
<type-enum>MyEnumContainer.MyEnum1</type-enum>
```

Of course it could also be

```
<type>com.company.project.tools.MyEnumContainer.MyEnum1</type>
<type package="com.company.project.tools">MyEnumContainer.MyEnum1</type>
```

let your imagination run wild...

Comment: This seems to answer my question, but I'll give it a shot once I'm in the office before approving the answer. I included the XML information as I had a feeling this might be the issue. Thanks a lot

Comment: I was thinking, it might also cascade, so you might need a `<type>MyEnumContainer</type>` followed by  `<type>MyEnumContainer.MyEnum1</type>`. So the first one finds the class, and second one finds nested classes

Comment: I realize now that this really is dependent on the system handling it. Unfortunately, it's out of my scope to modify it. Thanks for the extremely helpful information

Comment: If you're still monitoring this, it might also need an OS path rather than a package, so `<type>c:\source\com\company\project\tools\MyEnumContainer.MyEnum1</type>`